# Insert barcode into CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I would like to add a bar code to a CSV file that I generate in PHP I use a library called php-barcode-generator which generates bar codes in image or html. I have tried both ways and I have no barcode. Do you know what way to do to display barcode in a CSV?

This is what my code looks like:

```
$rows = [];
    $count = 0;
    $generator = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorJPG();
    foreach ($datas as $k => $data) {
        $rows[$k] = [
            'TJM',
            'TJM',
            '',
            '',
            strtoupper($data['reference']),
            $data['ean13'] ? $generator->getBarcode($data['ean13'], $generator::TYPE_CODABAR) : '',
            $data['quantity'],
            '',
            Configuration::get('EMAIL_ERROR'),
        ];

        if (Configuration::get('LOGS')) {
            file_put_contents($logs . '/PRODUCTS.log', 'Date de traitement: ' . date('d/m/Y H:i:s') . ' ID Product ' . $data['id_product'] . ' Réference: ' . strtoupper($data['reference']) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately the result is not conclusive

[image: csv]

Do you have any idea how I can display the image in the CSV? Thank you for your help

Comment: I do think that images and CSV are incompatible with (or to ?) another.

Comment: As far as I understand CSV are TEXTUAL files, typically meant to represent structured data. You can of course embed binary data encoded (image) encoded as text. But overall, you should know that a barcode in itself is also just a string. Thus, a barcode embedded in CSV is as simple as `Text;12345`. This sample text actually embeds a barcode reading "12345". So your question is ambiquous in several ways.

Comment: As everyone else is saying, CSV is text. If you want to put an image in there, what would be _reading_ this file? Excel? Notepad? Another computer?